# How do I access whatever I want from a JSON with FetchAPI?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I've started learning FetchAPI, so far i had no issues accessing whatever i want, but maybe that was the case because there was no arrays of objects in those examples, like there's in this one. I found some solutions online but they didn't work in my case. Any tips?

This is the JSON from a basketball API I found

```
  {
      "data":[
        {
          "id":237,
          "first_name":"LeBron",
          "last_name":"James",
          "position":"F",
          "height_feet": 6,
          "height_inches": 8,
          "weight_pounds": 250,
          "team":{
            "id":14,
            "abbreviation":"LAL",
            "city":"Los Angeles",
            "conference":"West",
            "division":"Pacific",
            "full_name":"Los Angeles Lakers",
            "name":"Lakers"
          }
        }
        ...
     ],
     "meta": {
        "total_pages": 50,
        "current_page": 1,
        "next_page": 2,
        "per_page": 25,
        "total_count": 9999
      }
    }
```

------------------ FETCH ---------------------

```
   fetch('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => 
        {
            console.log(data);
            
             // console.log(data.first_name)    --- doesn't work

             // console.log(data.team.city)     --- doesn't work
           
        });
    }
```

Comment: as you say, there are arrays and nested objects, so maybe go back to the basics and learn to handle rich data structures. This has nothign to do with the fetch api in the strict sense.

Comment: In the JSON, `data` is an array of objects, so you'll need to access its elements like `data[0].id` or iterate over `data` to get each object. Or really, because the variable is also named `data`, you'll need `data.data` (the "data" property of the "data" variable). But `meta` is an object, so `data.meta.total_pages` should work directly. It might be more clear if you change it to `.then(json => ` so then `json.data` and `json.meta` are more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This simple recursive function goes thru all properties of object and prints them. Up and down. It might help you visualize the objects involved and their "address" in the object tree.

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
    "id": 237,
    "first_name": "LeBron",
    "last_name": "James",
    "position": "F",
    "height_feet": 6,
    "height_inches": 8,
    "weight_pounds": 250,
    "team": {
      "id": 14,
      "abbreviation": "LAL",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "Los Angeles Lakers",
      "name": "Lakers"
    }
  }],
  "meta": {
    "total_pages": 50,
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page": 2,
    "per_page": 25,
    "total_count": 9999
  }
}

const iterate = (obj, level) => {
  if (!obj) {
    return;
  }
  level = level || 0
  var str_level = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 4 * level; i++) {
    str_level += "-"
  }
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(str_level + `key: ${key}, value: ${value}`)
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      iterate(value, level + 1)
    }
  })
}
iterate(data)
```